# Communication between website and Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I am new to Electron and pondering an approach to this problem: I already have a website that is attached to a database on a remote paid server; I need to build a standalone desktop app that could receive/send data from/to that database. Is there a way for that website to communicate with an Electron app (if so, what module is appropriate for this task).

I am trying to avoid rebuilding that website in the new app in order to read/write to the database.

If the above approach does not make sense or is not secure, if you could suggest a different approach or something for me to read up on, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for postgresql

```
npm i pg --save
```

**simple usage:**

```
const {Client} = require("pg");

const connectionString = 'postgresql://postgres:PASSWORD@localhost:5000/'

const client = new Client({
   connectionString: connectionString,
})

client.connect()

//SIMPLE SelectQuery
 let SelectQuery = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$1`
     client.query(SelectQuery,[id],(err,ress)=>{
         if(ress.rows.length>0){
            for (let f = 0; f < ress.rows.length; f++) {
              console.log(ress.rows[f].name)
             
           }
         }else{
            alert("no user")
         }
        
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

what use as database you?
postgresql, mysql.

almost all node js additions works on electron.

you must  install database addition on your app with npm

```
npm i mysql --save
```

for usage mysql on electron or node js

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: Cosar Thanks. The website uses postgresql. But I will read up on the mysql link you give. Thanks very much.